# Trigger Jenkins jobs from Gitlab is not working

Tags: nginx, jenkins, gitlab

I'm trying to execute my jobs automatically from Gitlab webhooks with this instructions:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin 
Now I have a Gitlab webhook when I test it the response is 200, but the response headers is

```
Response headers:

Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 24 Oct 2018 20:43:43 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Without response body

This is the expected response or an error?, my job is a multibranch pipeline, in Jenkins the job is not executed. My Jenkins work behind a proxypass with Nginx and the structure of my webhook url in Gitlab is https://jenkinsuser:jenkinsuserapiid@my.jenkins.server/project/myjob
In the Jenkins global configuration, in the Gitlab plugin in my Jenkins I can do a success test of the connection from Jenkins to Gitlab. I not have any idea about what is wrong
But in https://jenkinsuser:jenkinsuserapiid@my.jenkins.server/project/myjob what is myjob? 
This: DOT_testing-webhook
or this: view/DevOps/job/DOT_testing-webhook/job/master/

The execution of curl -X POST https://USER:API_ID@my.jenkins.com/project/DOT_testing-webhook/dev response:

### HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /project/DOT_testing-webhook/dev. Reason:

```
    Not Found
```

---

[Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT](http://eclipse.org/jetty)

---

Answer (score 0):

Response 200 looks OK. Response body depends on the plugin I guess. I use Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin and my response body has the Jenkins job name that was/ will be triggered. In your case maybe response body is blank because webhook could not find the job you configured in your webhook url or the plugin doesn't send any response back.

Your webhook URL should be in the below format as your job is within DOT_testing-webhook folder:

`https://USERID:APITOKEN@JENKINS_URL/project/DOT_testing-webhook/master` (if using global authentication - https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#configuring-global-authentication)

`https://JENKINS_URL/project/DOT_testing-webhook/master` (if using per-project authentication - https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#configuring-per-project-authentication) You will need to configure token in the Secret Token field in GitLab

Comment: I'm using Role-Based Strategy for the authorization, but when I use https://USERID:APITOKEN@JENKINS_URL/project/DOT_testing-webhook/master status 200 but the job is not triggered, however if I use the URL https://jenkins-user:########@my.jenkins.com/view/DevOps/job/DOT_testing-webhook/job/master/build , the job is executed